# Eclipse + Android GUI/UI Development Appropriate Strategy

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, user-interface

I'm going to try and ask this in a different way:

There are plenty of SO questions about GUI/UI development in Android and from what I understand since I am using Eclipse (unfortunately couldn't use PhoneGap or I think this would be a whole lot easier) I have to edit XML files to change my GUI/UI. If that is the case is the way most of you doing it is designing your programs in photoshop, and then somehow you splice it so you can work with it using XML? That's what I don't understand I am using the editor provided with Eclipse, but I don't want to just have basic boring boxes and text fields. I was hoping it be easier to customize than this.

Like basically is there really no other way to do this than by hand alter xml code and see what works and what doesn't? (I'm using ADT instead of DroidDraw so I've already created my buttons, etc that wasn't a problem)

Comment: Work through some tutorials. Tip 1: Eclipse's own tool is worthless at the moment (except perhaps the preview window which almost gets it right sometimes). If you want to do less pure xml I know there are tools out there, and some are mentioned here on SO. I haven't tried any of them though.

Comment: Try Droiddraw (http://www.droiddraw.org/), it is more well known of GUI tools. I haven't used it but heard good things about it. I personally like the control XML editing gives to me though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if that's what you choose to do it can be done.  the way you do it is to do whatever design you want for the interface, then go through using the slice tool slicing out all your different parts then to save it go to "file->save for web and select "export as html" and it will automatically save each of the slices as an individual pic and the proper html to call it all to the right locations... you would just have to go in and add links/functions to the buttons and any other elements you want to give a result when clicked.  I know you said you were using XML, but I'm sure you can tweak it over to call everything properly... but if possible you might want to do things in illustrator and export the image as an html5 image and use the canvas with javascript to call up the graphics all %100 code... there's a plugin you can download for AI that converts the vector art into canvas coordinates.. so you might want to look into that too... hope this helps.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to see if you like using IntelliJ Idea if you are willing to change your entire environment, since with version 12(which is available as a preview now, release slated for next month), an android UI designer is included and the video showing it looks very promising. 
http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2012/06/android-ui-designer-coming-in-intellij-idea-12/